# ASP.NET Web API 2 - single sign-on

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, owin

Is there any way to achieve single sign-on with separate `ASP.NET Web API 2` services and `OWIN Bearer Token Authentication` ? I want to have two separate `web.api` applications and don't want to sign in to second app when I'm alredy logged in first application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to centralize the OAuth2 authorization server the two Web APIs trust for tokens.

Comment: So I need make separate application for authentication ? I found http://thinktecture.github.io/, it will be good choice to use it for separate authentication server ?

Comment: Yes, that's what IdentityServer is for.

Comment: If I use separate IdentityServer (for ex. thinktecture), all operation like Register, ChangePassword should be invoked through this IdentityServer yes ?

Comment: Much of those operations will be custom for your requirements.

Comment: is there any sample code or tutorial for this? thanks.